# Change the ticket status after pull request is completed

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

I am using Git with Visual Studio and Azure DevOps. I am trying to complete a pull request and also change the ticket status.

Currently, you can do this by selecting the "Complete linked work items after merging". The problem is that this sets the status of the ticket to *Done*.

**Is there any way for the ticket status to be set with a different option on the completion of the pull request?**

It would also be nice to set a ticket status when you create a pull request...

Comment: What service are you using to handle the pull requests?

Comment: Visual Studio and sometimes in the browser w/ Azure Dev Ops

Comment: User voice: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1200823/ability-to-configure-target-work-item-state-after.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, agree with Shayki's answer. There does not such feature support by Azure Devops. Until now, this is a fixed option that you just can change it as completed while you complete the PR.

But, as work around, you can install an extension [WorkItem Updater](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BlueBasher.bluebasher-workitemupdater) which can change work item while build executed. And then, add the task **WorkItem Updater** into your build. In that task, you can change it as any state you want.

[image]

I know, this is not convenience for you to achieve what you want.

But also, here has an **UserVoice** raised on **Microsoft Developer Community** which is our main forum for product feature suggestions : [Customize Work Item State after PR is closed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365704/customize-work-item-state-after-pr-is-closed.html).

**Note:** You can vote and add your comment there. This UserVoice is already Under Review, I believe it will be meet soon.

Comment: Follow-up user voice: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1200823/ability-to-configure-target-work-item-state-after.html

Answer (score 10):

So this is actually in Azure Devops now - [Set Work Item State in Pull Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/add-links-to-work-items?view=azure-devops#set-work-item-state-in-pull-request)

Don't use `Complete linked work items after merging` if you don't want the Work Item to be closed. ;)

To set the status of Work Item 123 to `resolved` instead of `closed`, in your PR description write:

```
Resolved: #123
```

This feature is useful if you want change multiple tickets and uses the syntax `{state value}: #ID`. For example, to close a Task and resolve a User Story at the same time.

```
Resolved: #123
Closed: #456
```

However it does rely on developers knowing and using the convention instead of it being a managed policy across the organisation.

Comment: I cannot seem to set my task status to "Dev Complete" with this syntax.

Comment: @ΕГИІИО did you every figure out how to do states with a space in them?

Comment: @foldinglettuce nope. I moved away from using dev complete state for tasks. now I complete them when pr is merged and handle any reported bugs seperately.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this feature not available, you can't handle the work item state when you check "Complete linked work item after merging."

As workaround you can use [Service Hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks) to get the PR event and change the work item state to what you want (you need to write code that interact with Azure DevOps, there are many available API's).